# C preprocessor keep multiple lines

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I need to do the same thing on several arrays with different types in **C**.

Using `void *` I have written a function that will receive all types:

```
void
floatarraymanip(void *inarray)
{
  float *array=(float *)inarray;

  [SEVERAL LINES OF OPERATIONS]-------------
}                                          |
                                           |
void                                       |
longarraymanip(void *inarray)              ----> Same
{                                          |
  long *array=(long *)inarray;             |
                                           |
  [SEVERAL LINES OF OPERATIONS]-------------
}

void
arraymanip(void *array, char *arraytype)
{
  if(strcmp(arraytype,"FLOAT")==0)
    floatarraymanip(array);
  if(strcmp(arraytype,"LONG")==0)
    floatarraymanip(array);
}
```

The `[SEVERAL LINES OF OPERATIONS]` are exactly the same and relatively long (about 50 lines). I also need to do this for several other types, making the current version of my source code very long!

So my question is this: is there any way I can keep all these lines in the preprocessor in one command and just call that preprocessor variable in all these functions so the program becomes much shorter and more readable?

Comment: Simply define them as functions?

Comment: A preprocessor function?

Comment: Why not abstract away `[SEVERAL LINES OF OPERATIONS]` and make it a function. It will help in debugging, maintaining and keep the code clean. Long function macros are hard to maintain.

Comment: use \ at the end of line, new line right after the \. this won't break the macro. It look like you can do all the function as macro.

Comment: Just define them as normal functions.

Comment: @herohuyongtao, the problem is that in each, the type of `array` is different. But its name is the same.

Comment: @makhlaghi So maybe define a template function.

Comment: \ is a C escape key so you can use it in many more cases, for example writing a string in multiple lines. But you should use inline function instead, it's more typesafe and easier to debug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the whole function as macro like this:

```
#define MACRO(X) { \
                 first line command \
                 second line command \
                 third line \
                 last line \
                 }
```

You can also use the type as part of the macro:

```
#define MACRO(TYPE,X) { \
                 TYPE var = X; \ 
                 first line command \
                 second line command \
                 third line \
                 last line \
                 }
```

and call it like this:

```
MACRO(int, i)
MACRO(int*, p)
MACRO(float*, array)
```

**EDIT**
Better add {} ...

Comment: you can define the macro without parameter. but it look like it is what you want.